# How to edit and save stored procedure in Oracle toad?

Tags: oracle10g, toad

Can you please tell me how to edit and save stored procedure in Oralce using Toad.

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 10):

Open the Schema Browser, right-click on your stored procedure, select "Load in Editor". Make your changes, then click "Execute/Compile".

Comment: Such a hidden option if you don't know where to look :) Thanks.